# How to remove lines from files in a folder?

Tags: python, windows

I have a Python script that is able to remove lines in a file in a folder that contain certain keywords. It does this by creating a separate file and places it in a separate folder.

I would like to accomplish the same thing, but rather than do it on a per file basis I would like to apply it to all files within a specified folder. Here is what I have to accomplish this on a single file:

```
keywords = ['enable', 'password', 'secret', 'key', 'community']
file_name = str(input("Enter File Name:"))
with open(r"C:\Users\er\Desktop\\" + file_name) as oldfile, \
     open(r"C:\Users\er\Desktop\Clean_Files\\" + file_name, 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        if not any(keyword in line for keyword in keywords):
            newfile.write(line)
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`os.listdir(path='.')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir), use this loop, and then use it with the logic you already have:

```
import os

keywords = ['enable', 'password', 'secret', 'key', 'community']

for file_name in os.listdir('path\\to\\your\\directory'):
    with open(r"C:\Users\er\Desktop\\" + file_name) as oldfile, open(r"C:\Users\er\Desktop\Clean_Files\\" + file_name, 'w') as newfile:
        for line in oldfile:
            if not any(keyword in line for keyword in keywords):
               newfile.write(line)
```

Notice that if you don't pass a file to `os.listdir()`, it will use the current directory as path.

Alternatively, as mentioned by @pylang, you can use `pathlib.Path("path/to/dir/").iterdir()` instead of `os.listdir('path\\to\\your\\directory')`.

Comment: Alternatively, loop over `pathlib.Path("path/to/dir/").iterdir()`.

Comment: @pylang, thanks, I updated my answer adding your contribution.

Comment: I am getting an Exception Handling error stating that "name 'os' is not defined".

Comment: @erodr777, you have to import `os` module. I just updated my answer.

Comment: You guys are awesome! It works perfect. Thank you very much!